how to mis align two divs in css
I have a mobile and desktop design with css. My mobile design is also my desktop design and despite it fitting it isn't truly mobile ergonomic. I change the css when a certain width of px is decreased using media queries.
I'm wondering how I can make the green div on the right on top of the coral div so it is in order like div's normally are instead of in-line together. When I remove the inline bet however it seems to put the div on the right at the bottom instead of the top. I can't swap them around because it would mess up the layout and float:left/right doesn't work. Is there any way that I can fix the second div on the right to the top?


.bob1 {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: coral;
}

.bob2 {
  width: 17%;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
<div id='wrapper' style='text-align: center;'>
  <br>
  <div class="bob1">
    <div class="">
      <h1>
        This is a generic div ;)
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bob2">
    <div class="">
      <h1>
        This is a generic div ;)
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




You can use Flexbox for this. See https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/vWEMWw as an example (from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-examples). Compare how they do .aside-1 and .main to your .bob1 and .bob2 divs.

You could consider using a grid with bob2 placed in row 1 (or 2 depending on what you want that  to do) on the narrower viewports.

i appreciate the suggestions but as i said i rlllyyyyy dont want to change the structure and am hoping for a simple css solution doing with aligning.

My suggestion of a grid is pure CSS, no change of HTML structure, what is the problem with using it?

no your right my bad, i just want to avoid flexboxes. i will look into though!

tried applying    `#wrapper {
flex-direction: row-reverse;
display: flex;
}` and it still doesnt work, any suggestions? sorry,im terrible at flexboxes. I mean it works fine on the code previded but for my site it seems to do nothing? It is identical so idk whats going on

nvmd im an idiot ignore me, i got it to work!

FWIW <br> would likely be better as a padding-top:1em.  Please post what you ended up with as an answer and mark as  the accepted answer if indeed it does.  Not sure why you would avoid modern CSS such as flexbox or grid as all modern browsers support that and they often result in less CSS and simpler layout and work better for a responsive design.
